# dual boot Ubuntu and windows 10 black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, nvidia

[this is an image from the additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr86r.png) i originally had windows 10 installed on my Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IMH05 laptop which has the following specs 16.0 GiB Ram Intel® Core™ i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12 NV167 / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2) this is the graphics card shown in about page in about settings but also has  gtx 1650 and 250 gb ssd and 1t hdd i installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS along side windows as dual boot it worked fine for a couple of days but now when i start my laptop i do not see the menu to choose the OS and i get a black screen then it boots into Ubuntu. but i know that the menu is there since i can move using the arrow keys and choose windows 10 and i her the sound in windows 10 but still black screen and tried to enter the UEFI settings and still a black screen i installed both of the operating systems on the ssd  i tried using Boot Repair but still the same problem this is what i get when i use GParted  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCEUg.png)

i have an update after using the laptop on ubuntu for more than 2hr i restarted it and the menu showed up and i managed to boot into windows 10 normally also i do not understand the problem as i did not change anything and if it might be helpful one time the menu did show up but when i choose windows 10 vertical lines appeared on the screen and then went black again but this was before as for windows 10 updating yes there was an update on 23/5/2023 so before the problem started this is the update name (KB4023057: Update Health Tools—Windows Update Service components) but i do not know how to check for UEFI updates and if the settings reverted to defaults or not as for the nvidia driver i do not think that i installed any driver on ubuntu manually i just installed the os and that is it

boot-repair summary:

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230603_0254]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
nvme0n1p5/boot/efi not empty

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p5 ======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.1
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

uname -r
5.19.0-43-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Boot file info:      Grub2 (v2.00) in the file 
                       /ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso looks at sector 0 of 
                       the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not 
                       be found at this location.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on nvme0n1p5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic root=UUID=7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   96G   19G   73G  21% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: EGCN34WW(1.34) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (6C-24-08-74-4D-6A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x6)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(6c2408744d6a,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 4915A204-8394-49E2-95A0-BFD36269F198
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616 294229403 293989788 140.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 499030016 500115455   1085440   530M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 294230016 499030015 204800000  97.7G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xd9fa2484
      Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs::;
nvme0n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KBG40ZNT256G TOSHIBA MEMORY:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:151GB:151GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:151GB:256GB:105GB:ext4::;
4:256GB:256GB:556MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
└─sda1      ntfs     826A27C56A27B4B7                     d9fa2484-01                          Data  
nvme0n1                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     F02C-0A5A                            44d2a029-21cd-4e80-8cca-d322dac8cc00       EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               2ab36789-98cf-4aee-824f-163c530e1613       Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     82DC2CF3DC2CE361                     78127848-27a8-444a-a15c-b9f62360f144 OS    Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     085E99A85E998ED6                     80fc6f81-11bc-4003-adc4-4c079d227e64       
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302 92f88d54-d25d-4029-9b82-ecbd112467d3       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3                       85.9G  39% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                       88.5M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                       72.2G  19% /
/dev/sda1                           818.1G  12% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-43-generic   7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-42-generic   7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-F02C-0A5A
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=7b8221e4-476a-4b39-8e1e-564656840302 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=F02C-0A5A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 169.093544006 = 181.562810368  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 176.779914856 = 189.815988224  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 223.081050873 = 239.531454464  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic                 2
 176.779914856 = 189.815988224  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic                 2
 223.081050873 = 239.531454464  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 153.672561646 = 165.004656640  boot/initrd.img                                1
 178.299800873 = 191.447953408  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic              2
 153.672561646 = 165.004656640  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-43-generic              1
 178.299800873 = 191.447953408  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 ديس  2 17:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 ديس  2 17:18 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 ديس  2 17:18 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 ديس  2 17:18 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 ديس  2 17:18 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 سبت 20  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 ديس  2 17:18 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 ديس  2 17:18 41_custom
```

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. Did Windows do an update including updating UEFI. That would revert settings to defaults, you may need to re-review them. How did you install nVidia driver? From Ubuntu repository? UEFI should also have a setting on which video to use Intel or nVidia as default.

Comment: Please reformat your question to make it readable.

Comment: i see in your second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCEUg.png: windows system reserved have to fix by reboot with windows usb flash drive,select repair and fix startup.

Comment: thanks for your answer i will try it and inform you with the result

Comment: @TalaatEtman i manged to get my hands on windows usb flash drive but i can not use it  , when i restart the laptop a black screen appears and then boots directly to ubuntu

Comment: when you see your pc logo press f12 or f2, you can edit the bios settinges to aply usb drive as a first boot order